# Declaration of AdminDevis::getList() should be compatible with AdminTabCore::getList($id_lang, $orderBy = NULL, $orderWay = NULL, $st

Tags: php, standards, declaration

I read the other answers about this problem but I don't find the solution alone. I don't have this code or part of it in AdminDevis.php.

```
getList($id_lang, $orderBy = NULL, $orderWay = NULL, $start = 0, $limit = NULL, $id_lang_shop = false)
```

So I don't understand how I have to put it. And if is in this file that I have to put it.

Thank you

Comment: Please add the full error message to your question. Are you saying you don't have a method called `getList` in AdminDevis? If so does your class extend another class other than AdminTabCore? Is that overriding `getList`?

Comment: Please write a proper title and any code/error messages in your question instead.

Answer (score 0):

Both methods should accepts same parameters even though method of extending class won't get parameters don't know about what both methods do but closest to resolving error should be following

This should be base class

```
AdminTabCore::getList($id_lang, $orderBy = NULL, $orderWay = NULL, $start = 0, $limit = NULL, $id_lang_shop = false)
```

In remove warning you need to set method of class which extends AdminTabCore with same parameters

```
AdminDevis::getList($id_lang=null /*this one can be optional */, $orderBy = NULL, $orderWay = NULL, $start = 0, $limit = NULL, $id_lang_shop = false)
```